# Dynamics 365: Stop and Restart Enhanced SLA Timer Programatically

Tags: timer, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

So let say I have a Case that have an Enhanced SLA. Everytime a new email coming that is related to the case, I wanted to run a plugin that will stop/restart the SLA timer for the case (depending on the email content).

Is there any way to stop / restart the Enhanced SLA timer related to a case programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an Enhanced SLA and configure it to **Allow Pause and Resume**.

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/define-service-level-agreements-customer-service.aspx#bkmk_CreateEnhancedSLA:

> **Create an enhanced SLA**
>
> Make sure that you have the Customer Service Manager, System
>   Administrator, or System Customizer security role or equivalent
>   permissions.
>
> When you activate an SLA, a corresponding workflow is also created.
>   For every action you perform on the SLA, you must have permissions to
>   perform the same action on workflows. The SLA is applied in context to
>   the permissions that the owner of the SLA has.
>
> Check your security role
>
> Go to Settings > Service Management.
>
> Go to Service Level Agreements.
>
> To create a new SLA, click the New button.
>
> -OR-
>
> To edit an SLA, in the list of records, select the SLA, and then on
>   the command bar, click Edit.
>
> If you're creating a new SLA, you'll see the Create SLA dialog box.
>   Type a name for the SLA, and then select the entity for which you want
>   to create the SLA.
>
> Fill in your information
>
> Applicable From. Select the field that specifies the date and time
>   from which the SLA items will be calculated. For example, if you
>   select the Created On field, the calculations for service level
>   agreements will start from the time the record is created.
>
> Note You can have multiple SLA KPIs within one SLA. The start time for
>   different SLA KPIs within an SLA is set at the SLA level and can't be
>   different across SLA KPIs. The start time is determined by the
>   Applicable From field value. Business Hours. Select a customer service
>   schedule record that defines your support organization’s business
>   hours. This is useful in the SLA time-tracking calculations. If a
>   business hours record (customer service schedule) isn’t selected, the
>   work hours are considered to be 24 x 7.
>
> SLA Type. Select Enhanced.
>
> If you're creating an SLA for an entity other than Case,, this field
>   is automatically set to Enhanced, and can't be changed.
>
> Allow Pause and Resume. Select Allow if you want the SLA to pause
>   during the time the record is on hold. For each entity that's enabled
>   for SLA, you can set the statuses that will be considered “on hold” in
>   the Service tab of System Settings dialog box. More information:
>   System Settings dialog box - Service tab. You can set this field to
>   Allow only when you’re creating an enhanced SLA.
>
> Click Save.

Now you should configure the status values which will pause the SLA.

From: http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/11/dynamics-crm-2015-sla-enhancements.html:

> Automatically Pause/Resume the SLA time Calculation:
>
> Now with CRM 2015, administrators can setup specific Active Case
>   Status values that will automatically pause the SLA timer if the Case
>   is moved into one of the statuses selected.  When the Case is moved
>   out of that status, the timer will resume and continue.  This is
>   configured from Settings –> Service Management –> Service
>   Configuration Settings.
>
> In the example below, if a Case is moved into On Hold or Waiting for
>   Details, the SLA timer will pause (and this will reflect on the Case
>   form).  When the Case is moved back to In Progress or Researching, the
>   SLA timer will continue where it left off.  This functionality is only
>   available with Enhanced SLAs (described in more detail in the next
>   section).
>
> [image] 
>   [image]

You can now programatically change the case status, by updating the record (`IOrganizationService.Update`) to put the SLA on-hold and/or resume the SLA.